# Satis - not able to auth repository

Tags: composer-php, satis

I have followed the instructions at http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md to setup Satis.

I got to

```
php bin/satis build satis.json ./
```

but then get the following error:

```
 [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                                           
  The 'https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/repositories/companyName/myPackageName/tags' URL could not be accessed: HTTP/1.1 403 FORBIDD  
  EN
```

im guessing this is because its a private repository. Anyone know how to get around this?

My satis.json:

```
{
    "name": "Name Of Package",
    "homepage": "https://bitbucket.org/companyName/packageName",
    "repositories": [
        { "type": "vcs", "url": "https://bitbucket.org/companyName/packageName" }
    ],
    "require-all": true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are on your local machine where you already have access to that bitbucket repository.

Use the same URL that is used in your repository as the bitbucket remote location. If HTTPS does not work, try SSH instead.

Note that you have to run the Satis update on your local machine. If some other machine should run it, this machine also needs authenticated access to the bitbucket repository. Depending on your needs, you could share your private key on that machine, or create a new read-only account (Satis does not need to write).

Comment: im running this from an external server im adding may satis.json file to my original question now...